# Ambigious types in class definition haskell

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I am learning Haskell and in my pet project I defined several newtypes. When simplified, they are something like this

```
newtype A = A [Double]
```

I do not want type A to be created by just any list of doubles, but by list that satisfies some conditions. Moreover, I would like to be able to take the list, transform it by some function Double->Double and then create from it type A again. Since I want to do this for several different types, I was thinking about defining class

```
class Functor f => Transform a f b err where
  create :: f b -> Either err a
  get :: a -> f b
  transform :: (b -> b) -> a -> Either err a
  transform f a= create  (f <$> (get a)
```

And creating instance

```
instance Transformator A [] Double String where
   create [] = Left "err"
   create xs = Right $ A xs
   get (A xs) = xs
```

but this does not seem to be allowed in Haskell. The problem seems to be that return type of get is not the same as input type of create, the ambiguous type f in transform function cannot seem to be paired together between get and create.

In the end I gave up and solved the issue with two typeclasses:

```
class Transform a b err where
  transform :: (b -> b) -> a -> Either err a

class Create a b err where
  create :: b -> Either err a

newtype A = A [Double]

instance Create A [Double] String where
  create [] = Left "err"
  create xs = Right $ A xs

instance Transformator A Double String where
  transform f (A ps)= create  $ f <$> ps
```

This works quite nicely, but the transform function has always the same implementation - get data from inside the type, fmap function over them and apply create on the result.  Is there some way to make the default implementation work? Also, if you have some completely different suggestion how to approach the problem, I would be glad for any tips.

Comment: Why did you create that class? It feels very weird to me - very much like something that someone used to OOP would do, rather than someone used to Haskell. It has too many parameters, they're connected in what feels like a very ad-hoc manner. Is there anywhere in your code where you can implement something polymorphic in terms of that class and be satisfied with the results?

Comment: Haskell beginners shouldn't define their own classes at all. Learn to define functions, and types, and instances. These are the vast majority of actual Haskell code. As you do this, you'll get a good feel for what makes some classes really useful and others less so. You'll learn what makes some classes easy to use and others full of booby traps. Then when you find a good reason to actually define your own class, you'll go through a slew of bad class designs before you get good enough at it that only *most* of your attempts go badly. Designing good classes is really hard and rarely necessary.

Comment: When I say you should define types, I mean lots of them. Don't hesitate to define one or more datatypes and newtypes just so you can use them in your implementation of a single function. It's fine. One-off classes have their place, but they tend to involve careful judgement and/or advanced features.

Comment: @dfeuer Fair enough.  Is there some good source that would give nice tips like this to beginners? Or some good code out there that I could read and try to imitate its style? I only read through few books and now I am trying to somehow apply what I read. I am currently rewriting application that I wrote in java. The application is commercial and will most probably evolve in the future and I am curious to compare workflow between the two languages, hoping that if haskell proves to be better for development, as internet and haskell books say, I would manage to actually use it professionally.

Comment: @Umaxo, there's lots of interesting code on Hackage. I hear good things about haskellbook.com.

Comment: If `transform` is identical for all instances, it simply should not be a part of the class. Just move it out of the class to the top level. If this is the only method, then the entire class is not needed. In your last example though it does not seem identical for all instances because it has different implementation of the "get" part. Perhaps return the `get` function and use it instead of hardcoding ir in `transform`?

Comment: You may also want to look at https://wiki.haskell.org/Typeclassopedia especially at the Alternative class.